# Unable to deploy WSO2 APIM in Minikube Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, wso2, apim

I'm trying to deploy WSO2 APIM on Kubernetes using the pattern-1 described on the github page https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim. I have added my minikube ip to my etc/hosts file as follows:

[minikube ip] am.wso2.com gateway.am.wso2.com

I'm unable to access the Publisher and Devportal using this url:https://am.wso2.com/publisher

Is there any other configuration that needs to be done? Any help would be great:). Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you enabled and confiured the Ingress controller in Minikube?

Comment: Yes, using this command: minikube addons enable ingress

Comment: Are pods running?

Comment: Running Pods:
apim-v3-nfs-server-provisioner-0                 
wso2am-mysql-db-service-699bb96467-l5wcc

Comment: there are 4 wso2-am Pattern-1 pods that are not running, they are either in Crashloopbackoff, Pending, Init:0/1 state

Comment: Normally you cannot run the entire cluster in Minikube unless you reduce resource allocations to pods and increase resource allocation for minikube. Please update the ticket with the errors you are seeing on Pod startup so we can help you.

Comment: Right, as you just said the pod log says insufficient cpu.

Comment: I'll try increasing the resource allocations to the cluster

Comment: If you want to try out the product in K8s, I suggest deploying this single pod of APIM - https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/v4.1.0.1/simple/am-single

Comment: Okay, I'll try this in single pod and get back to you.. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Tried the Single-node APIM deployment by extending the minikube cpu and memory. All the pods have come to running state. But not able to access the publisher and devportal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure all your WSO2 pods are running and they're in the ready state.

```
kubectl get po -n <your_namespace>
```

This should output.

[image]

Then make sure you have enabled Ingress addon.

```
minikube addons list
```

[image]

Then make sure Ingress pods are running.

```
kubectl get po -n ingress-nginx
```

[image]

Next, get the Ingress external IP.

```
kubectl get ing -A
```

[image]

Get the external IP and the Host from the above and add a entry to the /etc/hosts as shown below.

[image]

If everything is in place you should be able to access the Publisher by going to https://am.wso2.com/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. All of my pods are running, enabled the ingress addon, added the external ip to hosts file. All my outputs are similar to yours, yet the portals are not accessible.

Comment: Can you tell me which service type you have used above? I am using the default type i.e ClusterIP. I have executed minikube tunnel. With this url : https://localhost:9443/devportal/apis, I am able to access the devportal. But all other portals like publisher, admin, carbon are not loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the below command in the command line.

```
minikube tunnel
```